# Summing certain values in a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, sum

I'm learning Ruby and I hope you can help me. This is my first question :)

I'm doing and exercise where I have the following hash:

```
sales = {
January: 15000,
February: 22000,
March: 12000,
April: 17000,
May: 81000,
June: 13000,
July: 21000,
August: 41200,
September: 25000,
October: 21500,
November: 91000,
December: 21000
```

}

I need to create a new hash called quarters with the total number amount of every trimester. This would be the output: `{"Q1"=>49000, "Q2"=>111000, "Q3"=>87200, "Q4"=>133500}`

This is the best I could do:

```
Q1 = sales[:January] + sales[:February] + sales[:March]
Q2 = sales[:April] + sales[:May] + sales[:June]
Q3 = sales[:July] + sales[:August] + sales[:September]
Q4 = sales[:October] + sales[:November] + sales[:December]

quarters = {
    "Q1"=> Q1,
    "Q2"=> Q2,
    "Q3"=> Q3,
    "Q4"=> Q4
}
```

The result is fine. 
My question is, which are better and simpler ways to do this? 
Please explain your answer. Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - when you've decided that one of the answers below correctly addresses your question, please click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: To be honest, your solution is very readable and concise and I think it will be easier for other people to understand right away. Also, given that the amount of months will always be constant (unless you introduce more years) you should consider if the abstraction is worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sergio beat me to it, but here is a slightly different solution:

```
quarters = {}
sales.values.each_slice(3).each_with_index {|a,i| quarters["Q#{i+1}"] = a.inject(0, :+) }
puts quarters
{"Q1"=>49000, "Q2"=>111000, "Q3"=>87200, "Q4"=>133500}
```

Note - inject(0, :+) works with Ruby versions back to 1.9, while `a.sum` is Ruby 2.4 and later and much faster than `inject` actually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
quarters={}
sales.each_slice(3).with_index(1) do |(a,b,c),i|
  quarters["Q#{i}"] = a[1]+b[1]+c[1]
end
quarters  # => {"Q1"=>49000, "Q2"=>111000, "Q3"=>87200, "Q4"=>133500}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link [each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) with [with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and [with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) methods.

```
quarters = sales.values.each_slice(3).with_index.with_object({}) do |(quarter, i), obj|
  obj["Q#{ i + 1 }"] = quarter.sum
end

# print quarters
quarters
#=> { "Q1" => 49000, "Q2" => 111000, "Q3" => 87200, "Q4" => 133500 }
```